# How is $ 2n + 10 \leq cn $ manipulated to $ (c - 2) n \geq 10 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have the inequality $ 2n + 10 \leq cn $, for all $n \geq n_0 $

I don't understand how this inequality is manipulated to $ (c - 2) n \geq 10 $

What are the steps involved?

Has ", for all $n \geq n_0 $" been incorrectly omitted from the derived inequality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2n+10\le cn\iff 10\le cn-2n\iff 10\le (c-2)n\iff (c-2)n\ge10$$

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to factorise $cn - 2n$